# Reverse XOR operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xor

I have 2 variables, `x` and `y`.

I am doing `z = x^y`.

Now assuming I know only `z` and `y`, How can I get `x` back? Is there an opposite to `^` in JavaScript?

Comment: Try this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540422/why-is-there-no-logical-xor-in-javascript/18064899#18064899

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, `^` is its own inverse.

```
x == (x^y)^y
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `z=x^y`

You can get `x` by doing `x=z^y`