# Exclusive OR in TypeScript

Tags: javascript

so i want to know how to implement or exclusive in type script

my problem is I have two conditions a and b I want to enter if statement only if one of them correct and the other is not

what I have tried is this

```
if((a==false && b==true) ||  (a==true and b==false)){
DO SOMTHING }
```

but I want a more clean version

Comment: You can use [bitwise xor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR).

`true ^ false = true`, `true ^ true = false`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no logical XOR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540422/why-is-there-no-logical-xor)

Comment: This is not a TypeScript problem.

Comment: @kelsny it's not only related to JavaScript, to TypeScript as well

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript prevents using the bitwise XOR on boolean types, even if it would execute because JavaScript converts them to `0` and `1` on the fly. So just go for `a !== b`.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADzgJwBQEMBciBGccANgKZZgA0BehJ5YAlIgN4CwAUIohAgM5REYOFADq6ANYwwAc0QBeRFkQA9AgG5O3XmAGIA7pOlzFygITzF%20TRwC%20QA)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use this comparison a lot, you could refactor the expression in a xor function that would return this result

```
const xor = (a: boolean, b: boolean) => ((a && !b) || (!a && b));
```

If you're doing a one time and want to save some character space, go for bit manipulation if both a and b are booleans (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR)

```
if(a ^ b) {
    // your stuff here
}
```

Though we could argue that bit manipulation might not be the most readable thing ever for someone that has never done it.