# Logical NAND,NOR,NXOR

Tags: javascript, web, calculator

I have written a logical calculator in JS.You have to chose numeric system for input numbers and to choose logical operation to do between them.Operations AND,OR and XOR works fine but i have problem with NAND,NOR,NXOR.When i do calculation with them script returns me negative value and value isnt even correct.

This is how i implement that in script:

```
 function logAND(num1,num2){
        return num1 & num2;//functions for calculating numbers by desired operations
    }
    function logOR(num1,num2){
        return num1 | num2;
    }
    function logNAND(num1, num2) {
        return ~(num1 & num2);
    }
    function logNOR(num1, num2) {
        return ~(num1 | num2);
    }
    function logXOR(num1, num2) {
        return num1 ^ num2;
    }
    function logNXOR(num1, num2) {
        return ~(num1 ^ num2)
    }
```

i also tried other variations like
`return ~(num1&num2) >>>0`
but it doesnt work too

this is how i output result

```
if (logop === "4") {
        result = logNOR(parseInt(inputnum1, stevsis), parseInt(inputnum2, stevsis));
        $("#result").html(result.toString(2) + " = " + result);
    }
```

also using ! instead of ~ doesnt help.It just returns "true=true" for example

Comment: can you post of couple of examples of "incorrect" outputs?

Comment: If you want *logical* operations, then why use *binary* operations? You say AND works, but if you expect `logAND(1, 2)` to be 0, then that is *not* a logical AND.

Comment: `~` is not logical not. It is bitwise not. `~1` is `-2` (because 1 is binary `000...0001`, so `~1` is binary `111...1110`, and 2 complement of that tells you that it is decimal -2). `!1` on the other hand is 0 (well, false)

Comment: And as @trincot said, sames goes for the operator you said are working. `&` is not the logical and. It is the bitwise and. `6&3` is `2`. Because 6 is binary `0...0110` and 3 is binary `0...0011`, so `6&3` is binary `0...0010` aka decimal 2, `6&&3` on the other hand is true. (because 6 and 3 are both logically true).

Comment: So, if you only use 1 and 0 as input, to mean `true` and `false`, `&` `|` seems "logical": `0&0 = 0&1 = 1&0 = 0`; `1&1`=1; `0|0=0`; `0|1 = 1|0 = 1|1 = 1`. Same if you decide that true is 12 (or any value, as long as you stick to it): `12&0 = 0&12 = 0&0 = 0`. `12&12=12`, `0|0=0`, `12|0=0|12=12|12=12`.  But that stops working with bitwise not (`~`). So, point is, use `&&`, `||`, `!` as logical and, or, not.

Comment: As for xor, there aren't any in JS (`^` is bitwise xor). But you can always use `!=`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540422/why-is-there-no-logical-xor